# Laravel 5.5 Parse error: syntax error when sending mail with php 7.0

Tags: php, laravel, gmail

I have issues when requesting password reset and sending mail, I use gmail with `lesssecureapps` enabled. 
and Whoops says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in 

/var/www/clients/client8/web8/web/vendor/symfony/css-selector/XPath/Extension/AttributeMatchingExtension.php
```

My novice mistake is I use php 7.1 in development while production environment is locked to 7.0.0

Is there a solution (using gmail in laravel 5.5 with php 7.0) without upgrading php version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a that the problem can be solved locking the php version inside the platform / config section of your composer file.

```
 "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.0.*"
        },
```

and then executing a `composer update` (and not a `composer install`), as the install will just follow your old composer.lock instructions.

you can see the github thread [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22955)

Please note that the composer update will update all your existing dependencies to the latest version available, and rewrite or create your composer lock.

Just beware of that before using this inside a production / live environment!

Comment: still doesn't works, same error message however this is my mail setup in .env

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=***@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: @McCandless how did you solve the error? i stuck with this